# How do I add custom buttons to Formtastic?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, button, formtastic

I'm using the Formtastic Rails gem in my app and its been great, but I would really like to add a second button, other than the bundled "commit" button that redirects back. I can't seem to find any information on how to add a custom button. Any information would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no custom or alternate buttons at this stage. You still have access to the raw HTML, ERB, Rails helpers, etc. Just use those.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, Justin. I noticed that formtastic puts the button in a nice <ol> with an <li>. Is there anyway to tell formtastic to include my ERB code in another <li>. Currently, I have 

http://pastie.org/892364

and it will include my link in the <ol>, but not give it an <li>. I feel like I'm just not using it properly.

Comment: Yup, you need to add your own LI.